# Vagrant, nodejs and iptable port forwarding

Tags: node.js, vagrant, iptables

I have a little issue when I try to use nodejs as a web server on vagrant (on OS X).

My config file is linked below, I have only nodejs and mongodb installed.
The box IP is `10.10.56.101` (I needed another ip than `192.168.56.101` to work at my school).

I try to reach the nodejs server with the little script linked below. The script only listen on port `51160` and answer OK.

First I didn't get any answers and after searching I found that I needed to do a port forwarding and with a iptable it worked (the command linked below, on port `51160` instead of `8000`).

I reinstalled the vagrant machine with the same configuration and I wasn't able to get the machine to work anymore.

I can `curl localhost:51160` from inside the vagrant machine but I can't get anything from outside the VM.

#### Files :

- config.yaml : https://gist.github.com/nobe4/0bb16fdb23279d416656
- server.js : https://gist.github.com/nobe4/639d63ef612f247d9309
- iptable command : https://gist.github.com/kentbrew/776580#file-node-on-ec2-port-80-txt-L39

Answer (score 3):

if you can `curl localhost:51160` from inside the vagrant machine, that means node.js service is file.

I didn't see the `Vagrantfile`, please check you have below lines in `Vagrantfile`

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 51160, host: 51160
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.123"   # or other unused IP.
```

After updated, run `vagrant provision`, and try again to access by

```
curl http://192.168.56.123:51160
```

from your own computer.

Comment: It works but initially I wanted to access the port 80. And when I set `guest: 51160, host: 80`. I get : `Failed to connect to 10.10.55.22 port 80: Connection refused`

Comment: 1. do you have web service running on your own computer? 2. set a fix private ip will be easier, which you needn't adjust IP address every time, when up the vagrant instance.

Comment: 1 : nop 2 : the guest private ip is fixed, I can have another fixed port than 80 but it was the one I wanted...

Comment: can you confirm by this command? run `telnet localhost 80` on your own computer, do you get connected or not?

Comment: `telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host`

Comment: do you have local admin right? active port (<1024)  for unix/linux server need root permission.

Comment: That is why I used the following method to get rid of launching node with sudo : https://gist.github.com/kentbrew/776580#file-node-on-ec2-port-80-txt-L39

Comment: Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277003/how-to-configure-vagrant-to-work-with-node-js