# Can't access localhost with vagrant port forwarding

Tags: localhost, vagrant, port, portforwarding

I can't access my forwarded ports outside my vagrant box shell.

I created a vagrant box with the following forwarded ports.

```
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: true
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 27017, host: 27017 #mongodb
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5000 #python flask port
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5050, host: 5050 # NODE Port

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

I have installed both a python server and a nodejs server. If I ssh in to my vagrant box and try: `curl http://localhost:5050` it correctly returns my nodejs hello world. If I `curl http://localhost:5000`  it correctly my python3 hello world.

However, I can't access my localhost outside the vagrant environment (with the servers in vagrant still active)

What am I doing wrong?

I am setting up a new machine - so it is possible I've not installed something essential on my localmachine but I have installed the dependencies for vagrant etc.

Pinging localhost or 127.0.0.1 works but only without a port. I am getting the following errors in terminal from my host machine outside vagrant:

```
$ ping localhost:80
ping: cannot resolve localhost:80: Unknown host
$ ping localhost:8080
ping: cannot resolve localhost:8080: Unknown host

$ curl 'http://localhost:80'     
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
$ curl 'http://localhost:8080' 
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
$ curl 'http://localhost:5000'
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
$ curl 'http://localhost:5050'
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
$ curl 'http://127.0.0.1:80'    
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
$ curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
$ curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
$ curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5050'
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

& the below from the static ip, after a short delay for each...

```
$ curl 'http://192.168.33.10:80'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.33.10 port 80: Connection refused
$ curl 'http://192.168.33.10:8080'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.33.10 port 8080: Connection refused
$ curl 'http://192.168.33.10:5000'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.33.10 port 5000: Connection refused
$ curl 'http://192.168.33.10:5050'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.33.10 port 5050: Connection refused
```

I am using Mac OS Catalina. My firewall is disabled & allowing all connections.

Output of `sudo netstat -ntlp` within the vm..

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      469/rpcbind         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      510/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      865/sshd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      790/postgres        
tcp        0      0 192.168.33.10:5050      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2730/node           
tcp        0      0 192.168.33.10:5000      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4070/python         
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      469/rpcbind         
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      865/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      790/postgres
```

It seems to be similar to the problem here but my vagrantfile has the right lines in it: [Vagrant, nodejs and iptable port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526391/vagrant-nodejs-and-iptable-port-forwarding)

I've also double checked everything pointed out in about 10 questions like this:
[vagrant port forwarding doesn't work: Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103449/vagrant-port-forwarding-doesnt-work-connection-reset-by-peer)

Comment: Just FYI, `ping` uses ICMP, which doesn't have ports like TCP. You should be able to `ping localhost` or `ping 192.168.33.10`, but `ping localhost:8080` will never work.

Comment: Also, because you've assigned the VM an IP address on a private network you shouldn't need to setup port forwarding. Instead (once your issue is resolved), you can just `curl 192.168.33.10:5000` and `curl 192.168.33.10:5050` directly.

Comment: Assuming your Vagrant VM is a Linux machine, can you show us the output of `sudo netstat -ntlp`? It would be beneficial to see what services are listening on what ports, e.g. perhaps your Python and NodeJS services are only listening on 127.0.0.1 - which means they wouldn't respond to requests to 192.168.33.10. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - I've added the output of netstat. Also, useful to know that pinging localhost with a port won't work. The only reason I tried a private IP was because I couldn't make sense of localhost. I'd like to be able to curl localhost:5000 (etc) or visit it in my browser!

Comment: have you tried specifying the host in both your flask and node app to '0.0.0.0' ?

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Comment: @Dreamystify Sadly not. I've had issues with port forwarding with vagrant for years so I think, as much as I like what it does (when it works), I am past using it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `config.ssh.extra_args` option](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings) for that.

That could give something like:

```
  config.ssh.extra_args = ["-L", "80:localhost:8080", "-L", "27017:localhost:27017", "-L", "5000:localhost: 5000", "-L", "5050:localhost: 5050"]
```

Doing so is equivalent to running several port forwards with ssh (from your vagrant project's repository):

```
ssh -N -n -L 80:localhost:8080 -L 27017:localhost:27017 -L 5000:localhost:5000 -L 5050:localhost:5050 192.168.33.10 -i `pwd`/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key -X
```